# Why does Swift unexpectedly insert “Optional” at the beginning of stringFromData?

Tags: swift, string, option-type

I run this code on an iPad to create virtual BLE peripheral.
It starts advertising.
I run the central on iPhone.
Central detects peripheral and connects and subscribes.
Peripheral log unexpectedly has "Optional" in the log, though it's not in stringFromData.

IMAGE SHOWS stringFromData CONTENT AND LOG.........

[image]

```
class PeripheralViewController: UIViewController {
    var packet_to_send = Data()

. . .


    func peripheralManager(_ peripheral: CBPeripheralManager, central: CBCentral, didSubscribeTo characteristic: CBCharacteristic) {
        os_log("Central subscribed to characteristic")
        
        // Init 1st sim packet:
        packet_to_send = ("antenna data chunk " + String( packet_number )).data(using: .utf8)!         
            let stringFromData = String(data: packet_to_send, encoding: .utf8)
            os_log("initial packet_to_send %d bytes = '%s'.", packet_to_send.count, String( describing: stringFromData))
```

Comment: Because not all data is convertible to String using UTF8 encoding. Just try to transform a JPG into String using UTF8, you'll see. In your case, you shouldn't have an issue, but the compiler can't guess it. So `stringFromData` is an optional, no?

Answer (score 2):

`stringFromData` is an `Optional`. When you use `String(describing:)` to get the description of an `Optional`, it will be `"Optional(yourDescription)"` rather than `"yourDescription"`.

You can avoid this by converting the `Optional<String>` into a `String` using optional binding or by providing a default value.

```
let stringFromData = String(data: packet_to_send, encoding: .utf8) ?? ""
os_log("initial packet_to_send %d bytes = '%s'.", packet_to_send.count, stringFromData)
```